# JavaScript WebWorker not executing from onClick

Tags: javascript, onclick, web-worker

I have a web worker specified as such below:

```
var w;
function startWorker() {
    if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
        if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
            w = new Worker("scripts/gameengine.js");
        }
        w.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log("Testing web worker");
        };
    } else {
        console.log("No support for web workers");
    }
}


 function stopWorker() {
    w.terminate();
    w = undefined;
}
```

However; when I run `startWorker();` from an onClick function I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on line 117
```

line 117 is `w.terminate()`; in my `stopWorker`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the click handler fires twice, `w` will be undefined on the second invocation.

Defensive programming is advisable, for these reasons:

The code should only call things that are well-defined; otherwise JS tends to block execution of later statements

Properly handled, the console.log can be used to tell you what is happening

```
function stopWorker() {
    if ( w && (typeof(w.terminate)==='function') ){
       w.terminate();
       w = undefined;
       console.log('terminated worker per click request');
    } else {
       console.log('received click request to terminate worker, but worker undefined');
    }
}
```

Also, be aware that the last time I checked, workers could not access browser functionality, and could only do message passing back to the main script.  That means no jQuery, no event handling, no trying to write to objects on the screen, etc. Just computing and message passing.

Comment: It shouldn't fire twice; however I will attempt this.

Comment: Implementing your code did show the second console log; is there a reason for this that can be avoided?

Comment: I have my onClick based off of hovering over objects that I created. So if a click is detected as well as hovering over an object is happening then it should activate the click event.

Comment: Are you also getting the correct behavior as well as the 2nd click?

Comment: No; I am not getting the expected console logs from the startWorker(); it appears as if it is never being called.

Comment: So is w a global?  I see the `var w` and maybe you don't want that. Globals in the main task are actually properties of `window`.  Sometimes an explicit `window.w = blah` is a good thing.

Comment: I'm sorry; bit new to JavaScript. So you mean if I instantiate `var w` and call `window.w` it should make it global? Or is there a different way to instantiate on the `window` property?

Comment: Secondarily; `window` is a `canvas` in this case?

Comment: In the browser, there is always a global called `window` that refers to the browser window.  But `window` also contains all the globals (the variables in the code that did **not** use var). The canvas is  not the window. So to make w global, you can **avoid** using **var w** or use window.w to make it explicit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66332/discussion-between-tukajo-and-paul).